# how to explode the string containing quotes in the field

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

hey i am new to Joomla  and always a learner please some one help me  that i am exploding the string  which i am retrieving from the database of Joomla com_content. it is the path of the image. after fetching the data i have got.

```
$img="images\/sample-image-big.png"
```

after that i am exploding it to get only the name of the image so i have removed /  after that the result is coming,

```
 Array (
     [0] => "images
    [1] => sample-image-big.png" )
```

the problem is that the array[1]=> should be only sample-image-big.png  but the " is coming why i want it to remove it , ihave tried all types of explosion but no change , please help me i will be very much thankful to u.

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
<?php

$img="images\/sample-image-big.png";

$img=explode("\/",$img);

print_r($img);
```

**output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => images
    [1] => sample-image-big.png
)
```

Comment: What is you program going to do when the image is in the images/animals folder (images/animals/koala.jpg)?  I really think explode is probably not how you want to do this.

Comment: actually i want show image on my template.which the article consisting , so i am trying to use the item.id to fetch the data  from the com_content, after that i want to get the image path which creates complications . is there any other way than exploding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img="images\/sample-image-big.png"
```

stripslash your string

```
$img=stripslashes($img)// this will give you "images/sample-image-big.png"
```

now various ways to get what you need. Simplest for me:

```
$img = str_replace('"images/', '', $img); // will give sample-image-big.png"
$img = str_replace('"', '', $img); // will give sample-image-big.png
```

Comment: is your $img = str_replace("', '', $img); // will give sample-image-big.png  is right because it gives me error. else its right iam close to it . please check  and send the correct format. thankyou.

Comment: @racial cortis check now